# Not able to bind dynamic data to select2 datasource

Tags: jquery-select2

we are using select2 v4 with the knockout. Initially, we are loading option for select2 at '`select2:open`' event but when adding data to select2 Datasource control gets rebuild. we wanted to have dynamic data-bind for select2 without rebuilding the control.

Html file code:

```
<select class="control" data-bind="select2: { dataSource: temp, placeholder: 'Enter data', originalPlaceholder: 'Enter data',} "></select>
```

js code:

```
    function initialiseSelect2($element, settings) {
        $element.select2(settings); //here select2 element get rebuild
        $element.select2('data',settings.datasource); //wanted to have something like this, but not working
```

Can you please help me in this?
Thanks in advance